Microsoft Graph API is returning UnknownError (Log in with Microsoft)
I am creating a "Log in with Microsoft" button using PHP. With the code below, I can obtain an Access Token, but when I make a cURL request to retrieve user information with the obtained Access Token, I get an unknownError. What's the problem?
API permissions: Microsoft Graph (User.Read)
ms-login.php
<?php
$clientId = 'CLIENT_ID';
$redirectUri = 'REDIRECT_URI';

$authorizationUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
$params = [
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
    'response_mode' => 'query',
    'scope' => 'openid profile email',
];

$authUrl = $authorizationUrl . '?' . http_build_query($params);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Log in with Microsoft</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($authUrl); ?>">Log in with Microsoft</a>
</body>
</html>

ms-callback.php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $code = $_GET['code'];

    $tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    $clientId = 'CLIENT_ID';
    $clientSecret = 'CLIENT_SECRET';
    $redirectUri = 'REDIRECT_URI';

    // Data required to obtain the access token
    $tokenRequestData = [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'code' => $code,
        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
    ];

    // POST request to get access token
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $tokenUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($tokenRequestData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded']);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        exit;
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    $response = json_decode($response, true);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
    echo "</pre>";

    if (isset($response['access_token'])) {
        $accessToken = $response['access_token'];

        // Request to obtain user information
        $userInfoUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $userInfoUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ]);
        $userInfo = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
            exit;
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        $userInfo = json_decode($userInfo, true);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($userInfo);
        echo "</pre>";
    } else {
        echo 'Could not get the token';
    }
} else {
    echo 'The authorization code could not be obtained.';
}
?>

Output:
Array
(
    [token_type] => Bearer
    [scope] => openid profile email
    [expires_in] => 3600
    [ext_expires_in] => 3600
    [access_token] => 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
    [id_token] => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImRHdEhRTWhHbHRKVUNjSF9TUVc2NG5FVW9ZRSJ9.eyJ2ZXIiOiIyLjAiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vOTE4ODA0MGQtNmM2Ny00YzViLWIxMTItMzZhMzA0YjY2ZGFkL3YyLjAiLCJzdWIiOiJBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFJWVVLZ29qRjlJSjJnNXIzRVBWSlhnIiwiYXVkIjoiMWVhZjM5N2QtM2M5ZC00MmUyLWIxYmItYzA0YjQwOThkY2I3IiwiZXhwIjoxNzIyNzEyNzA1LCJpYXQiOjE3MjI2MjYwMDUsIm5iZiI6MTcyMjYyNjAwNSwibmFtZSI6IsSwYnJhaGltIMWeZW4iLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJicmhtc244MEBvdXRsb29rLmNvbSIsIm9pZCI6IjAwMDAwMDAwLTAwMDAtMDAwMC1jYjdlLWRiZDZhOWQ0YzEyZSIsImVtYWlsIjoiYnJobXNuODBAb3V0bG9vay5jb20iLCJ0aWQiOiI5MTg4MDQwZC02YzY3LTRjNWItYjExMi0zNmEzMDRiNjZkYWQiLCJhaW8iOiJEc29KcWF0Z1RNQXU3dHdtekxsV3piZnk1ZnhyZlJjVmoxY0FYb2pIVEFQbzZubTEyZ2NBcmIzOThVa2ZxQTgyWXZ5UGFsMWZSKktia3hQSjhIS215SUJsd2swdGFzcHhTVEZ0YTA4aDRldEtFTjA0UEhBIXhsUk1ENEYwciEhKlcqWkFITW8xcCF2blJMRHNxTlMzTnllSWlvSURyeEM5NDBxKnlVa3RjelNYIn0.CgDSqoTlK4EXutgXWj4Qh9L1jra1nuQE1BUSK6Gwu_ljwVdIPci7U0e-y88_WhW1IAfoy_7Jb1n2P0L3tSmx2UXccyLak0sthVfyEBsUdunTiaBKUjIab2tYvUsr4gJKF0tsIKAh6y9fagbfKOuvVPKsUiwS9fcmxN_-A5QzxUNFkz0Bk75AVuLPwC3gESz04EZMETjaKATdkietAvNemP-sKwqOAmlgvUu5yR2HwgbH3eUh9QAoG8ELZAP2vw0IjEjG-FI9c7BIpmHyFqMmhzsb-LGEqpKJBNOLe95Vrap_CJtQPUCP45VTZ0zDvekVZ1iBvpjfEFa6_f-LX_uZCg
)
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [code] => UnknownError
            [message] => 
            [innerError] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2024-08-02T19:18:26
                    [request-id] => 7cd0296a-e68c-4505-ad90-428ffd2ece22
                    [client-request-id] => 7cd0296a-e68c-4505-ad90-428ffd2ece22
                )

        )

)


On the first sight, access_token EwB4... mentioned in the output is definitely not an access token. id_token looks like an access token. Try jwt.io to check which one is valid token

I solved it by changing the following line of code in "ms-login.php":
'scope' => 'openid profile email' to 'scope' => 'openid profile email User.Read'
